# how to remove logo image hyperlink for wordpress

Tags: navigation, logo

can any one tell how to remove the navigation menu for mobile & desktop view. and how to stop the logo redirection URL.

Comment: What is your site URL? Which theme are you using?

Comment: You need to give people more to go on, like the theme you're using, what you've tried to do to achieve your aims, etc, that you can't get to work.